# Insert React variable as attribute in html tag

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to obtain the following line

```
<a href="/users/users/authentication" rel='nofollow'>
```

Note the **rel='nofollow'**

Within the render method of my React component, I have this JSX syntax :

```
render() {
  const rel = "rel='nofollow'";
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="/users/users/authentication" {rel}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get a :
*Error: /~/Scripts/Navigation.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "..."*

I also tried with

```
let rel = { __html: "<b>Hey</b>" };
```

and

```
<a href="/users/users/authentication" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={rel}>
```

which fails too but anyway dangerouslySetInnerHTML is supposed to inject some stuff between the opening and closing tag not *within* as an attribute of the  tag.

What would be the correct JSX syntax to make that happen ?

Comment: You don't have to to change anything about HTML syntax to set a basic attribute in React, unless it's a multi-word attribute, which in some cases is camelCased.  But simply putting ```<a href="/users/users/authentication" rel='nofollow'>``` should work.

Comment: I believe this is exactly what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619182/what-is-the-best-way-to-have-variable-attributes-in-jsx

Answer (score 9):

You'd first have to decide what "shape" of your `rel` value should be. Would it be a text? or would it be an object?

## 1 `rel` is a text.

If the `rel` is passed as a raw text, such as `nofollow`, you'd have to assign the `rel` property manually.

```js
function LinkWithPropertyAssignment() {
  const rel = "nofollow";

  return (
    <a href="https://www.google.com" rel={rel}>
      Google
    </a>
  );
}
```

## 2 `rel` is an object.

If the `rel` was passed as an object, such as `{rel: 'nofollow'}`, then you can simply pass the object to the anchor element.

```js
function LinkWithObjectSpread() {
  const rel = { rel: "nofollow" };

  return (
    <a href="https://www.bing.com" {...rel}>
      Bing
    </a>
  );
}
```

You can see that both will add `rel='nofollow'` attribute.

[image: rendered HTML]

## Demo

You can follow along on CodeSandbox.
[image: Edit so.answer.56133987]

Answer (score 0):

```
  render() {
  const theRel = "nofollow";
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="/users/users/authentication" rel={theRel}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `rel` like this:

```
render() {
  const rel = "nofollow";
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="/users/users/authentication" rel={rel}>Hey</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```